# Привязка dataGrid к нескольким классам

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Возник вопрос каким образом возможно задать привязку (binding) в dataGrid к более чем одной сущности (речь идет о классе для отображения таблицы из БД)?
Очень сомнительным видится применение 3 элементов dataGrid или привязка к ячейкам по индексу (например, прямо указать столбцы [0]), поэтому хотелось бы разобраться и использовать механизхм привязки.

---

Утояняю вопрос:

Как привязать к одному dataGrid более чем один источник данных с использованием привязки, например c одним источником необходима привязка и структура отобржения данных представленная ниже:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding dateAuthorizLic, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm\}}" Header="Дата выдачи"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding nameProgram}" Header="Программа"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding nameCustomer}"  Header="Заказчик"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Для отображения данных из другого источника, потребуется следующая привязка:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding nameKor}" Header="Корректор"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Наименование"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding count}"  Header="Количество"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: а почему не 3 разных экземпляра `view`? типы полей разные, данные разные, для чего Вы хотите сделать один *универсальный* грид?

Comment: Да, один универсальный, так как в активном режиме использется только один. Сейчас реализованы 3 грида, и мне кажется это не самое лучше решение, хотела бы посоветоваться на этот счет.

Comment: на текущий момент у Вас это все таки 2 разных грида(они похожи только кол-вом колонок), как мне кажется, здесь должно быть все таки 2 грида.

Comment: @Bald я привела как пример)

Comment: Автогенерирование столбцов включите

Comment: @АндрейNOP в таблицах много служебной информации, кототрая пользователю не нужна.

Comment: Ну значит вам надо генерировать столбцы вручную, в зависимости от привязанных данных. Проблема еще в том, что откуда-то надо получать информацию о том какие свойства у текущей сущности надо отображать, а какие не надо, какие наименования столбцов должны быть (nameKor - это Корректор), как форматировать вывод определенного свойства (типа `{Binding dateAuthorizLic, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm\}}`)

Comment: Ну а так — не сложно, подписываетесь на изменение источника, удаляете столбцы и генерируете их заново.

Comment: `в таблицах много служебной информации` - вот для таких целей и реализуют MVVM подход, где все делится на слои. База - Model. То, что видит пользователь - View. Связывающий слой (где вы скажем берете из базы только необходимую для отображения инфу) - ViewModel.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ к тому и идем

Comment: @АндрейNOP не могли бы вы про подписку на изменение поподробнее подсказать? Копать в эту сторону (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-control-when-the-textbox-text-updates-the-source )

Comment: Не, тут скорее `NotifyOnSourceUpdated`/`NotifyOnTargetUpdated` надо смотреть. Да, в привязке укажите `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` и обрабатывайте событие `Binding.TargetUpdated`/`TargetUpdated` (в нем перегенерируйте столбцы)